Find exists array in array same values not same orders
const array = 
[
[1,2,3],
[4,1,1,3]
[5,5,7]
]
const newArray = [2,3,1]

How I can find with javascript if this array exists in the array (exists with other order)
I sloved this by sort the array
and check with JSON.stringify
    let conflictIds = [...conflictsList.map(c=>c._id), ssdst._id]
            conflictIds =  conflictIds.sort();
        if(!existsInArray(conflictsArr, conflictIds)){
            const conflictObj = {schedules:conflictIds   .... }
    conflictsArr.push(conflictObj)
                                        }
                
const existsInArray = (array, newElement)=>{
return array.find(arr=>JSON.stringify(arr.schedules) ===JSON.stringify(newElement) )
}


also see: How to compare arrays in JavaScript?

"array in array" means that the second array could be bigger. To find the result we need collect counts of values and then substract counts from the first array. If there's any negative count value that means that the second array doesn't contain all values to recreate the first array:


const array = [
  [1, 2, 4, 2, 3],
  [4, 1, 1, 3],
  [5, 5, 7]
];

const newArray = [3, 2, 1, 2];

function doesIncludesValuesFromArray(arr, newArray){
  if(newArray.length > arr.length) return false;
  const counts = arr.reduce((r, n) => (r[n] = (r[n] ?? 0) + 1, r), {});
  for(const n of newArray){
    counts[n] = (counts[n] ?? 0) - 1
    if(counts[n] < 0){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

array.forEach(arr => console.log(...arr, '=>', doesIncludesValuesFromArray(arr, newArray)));




You can calculate the frequencies of elements in each array and compare them.


const array = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 1, 1, 3],
  [5, 5, 7]
];
const newArray = [2, 3, 1];
const getFreq = arr => {
  const freq = new Map;
  for (const x of arr) freq.set(x, 1 + freq.get(x) || 1);
  return freq;
};
const newArrFreq = [...getFreq(newArray)];
let found = array.some(arr => {
  const currFreq = getFreq(arr);
  return currFreq.size === newArrFreq.length && 
    newArrFreq.every(([k, v]) => v === currFreq.get(k));
});
// use find instead of some to get the actual array that matched
console.log(found);




7 and 12 year duplicates.

@pilchard I feel like you missed the part about ignoring order.

pretty sure 'ignoring order' is covered in one of he 103 answers in the duplicate (in fact on the very first page of answers)

@pilchard That isn't the criteria for duplicates, but to each their own.

The number is just the example the array is array of strings....

@24sharon That doesn't change my answer in the slightest. Maps work fine with strings too.
